# Why does `const` work on the thing immediately preceding it?

Tags: c++, c, syntax, constants

I am learning C++. In my course, it is explained that it is best to place `const` immediately *after* the thing you want to make unchangeable, because this is how `const` works.

Many people, including for instance Bjarne Stroustrup himself, like to write `const` in front. But this sometimes leads to problems:

```
const int *foo; //modifiable pointer to a constant int. 
int const *bar; //constant pointer to a modifiable int? No! It's a modifiable pointer to a constant int. (So the same type as foo)
```

An example that shows this in action:

```
int fun(int const *mypointer)
{
    *mypointer = 5; //Won't compile, because constant int.
    mypointer = 0; // Is okay, because modifiable pointer.
}
```

What makes this even more confusing, is that compilers such as g++ like to rewrite `int const bar` to `const int bar` in their error messages.

Now, this behaviour is confusing me greatly. Why does `const` work in this way? It would seem a lot easier to understand if it would 'just' work on the thing put after it.

Comment: C's insane type specifier syntax is mostly an accident of history.

Comment: And then C++ wanted to provide backwards compat for the most part so they stuck with it.

Comment: _But this sometimes leads to problems_ <-- Usually, it leads to problems when you don't know how it works.

Comment: You want `int const *` to mean "`int *`, made `const`", even though `const` separates the `int` and the `*`? How is that more logical than "pointer to `int const`"?

Comment: @GillBates `const` was introduced by Stroustrup ("C with classes") and later adopted by ANSI C.

Comment: @molbdnilo I was actually talking about the general case of type specifier syntax, as Sebastian said.

Comment: What I am doing usually (just because I want to avoid this confusion) is either put it at the end or beginning and never in the middle. Like `const int* foo` and `int * const foo`. This may be a personal style taste but it's clearer for me and does not lead to confusion when you "forget" which way const evaluates first.

Comment: If you want a constant pointer to a modfiable int: `int * const foo`

Comment: The rule makes (slightly) more sense [when you need more than one `const`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143262/what-is-the-difference-between-const-int-const-int-const-and-int-const/1143272#1143272)

Comment: Another reason to avoid pointers whenever possible.

Comment: ?is front to back syntax C's is Why

Comment: The rule is to read it from right to left. `int const*` = pointer to const int.

Comment: *But this sometimes leads to problems <-- Usually, it leads to problems when you don't know how it works* <-- He was right; contra-intuitive language syntax does lead to problems, because it requires remembering more rules.

Comment: @stenliis, why on earth did you remove the `c` tag?

Comment: @Aziuth, I hope you're kidding. The ugly (in some parts) syntax of C has absolutely no relation to valid reasons not to use pointers. The pointers as a feature is one thing and syntax of their declaration is quite another.

Comment: If you think that code was confusing, how about `const int const signed const const const *foo;`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C++ follows syntax of C.

It looks weird, but in C you specify **not a type of variable**, but **a type of expression with it**:

- `int v` means that `v` is `int`;
- `int *v` means that `*v` is `int`, so `v` is pointer to `int`;
- `int v[]` means that `v[…]` is `int`, so `v` is array of `int`;
- `int v()` means that `v()` is `int`, so `v` is function returning `int`;
- etc (you always need to read such declaration from inner).

More closely to your question, in C type specification can consist of several words: `unsigned char`, `long int`, `const double` (even more than two — `const unsigned long long int`). Number of repeated words matters (`long long int` in general case is different from `long int`), but order of words doesn't (`long int` is the same as `int long`). That's why `const int *p` is the same as `int const *p` (as well as `const int i` is the same as `int const i`).

As for `int * const p`, it probably doesn't obey common scheme. As there is no such expression as `* const p` (where `p` is a variable) in C, so we can't explain it with something like *"expression `* const p` will have type `int`"*. However, think, where else can we put `const` keyword to specify that pointer itself is constant, not its dereferenced value? (Assuming that both `const int *p` and `int const *p` mean that a dereferenced value is constant, and we don't want to introduce additional keywords into language.) Nowhere except after `*`; so here it goes.

Answer (score 1):

To understand a C declaration there is a [Right-Left rule](http://ieng9.ucsd.edu/~cs30x/rt_lt.rule.html) that is very helpful: For example

```
int *
```

is a pointer to an integer (note that you have to read that right to left). Same thing for reference to int:

```
int &
```

Now read the type of p8 from right to left:

```
char * const * const p8; //  const pointer to const pointer to char
```

I suspect that const modifies the preceding type, just to be consistent with that rule. The fact that you can put const in the very beginning of the declaration is an exception.

Note: the example comes from [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7042/How-to-interpret-complex-C-C-declarations#const) (but I changed it slightly).